# Логика выбора уникальных записей из mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть таблица под названием personal043. В этой таблице есть `id`, `card_id`, `zubno`, `naimenovanie`, `date`.

- `id` - всем понятная и нужная вещь
- `card_id` - номер карты пациента
- `zubno` - номер зуба
- `naimenovanie` - наименование изменений в полости рта (пломба, коронка, удаление зуба и т.д)
- `date` - дата когда были изменения

Необходимо вывести количество измененных зубов на определенную дату. Например:

02.02.2017 - 2 зуба изменились (т е у одного пломба, а второй зуб удалили)

05.03.2017 - 3 зуба изменились

06.06.2017 - 1 зуб изменился и т.д. (ВАЖНЫЙ МОМЕНТ: здесь в одном зубе могут быть несколько изменений (кариес, пломба и т.д), но нужно иметь ввиду что меняется только один зуб)

Хотел сделать так:

`SELECT zubno DISTINCT date COUNT(*) FROM personal043 WHERE card_id = $id GROUP BY date`

Он у меня выдал ошибку. Для того чтобы реализовать вышеописанное нужно брать дату и уникальный номер зуба, как сделать это? В общем, надо узнать не сколько изменений на один зуб, а сколько зубов были изменены на определенную дату. 
Сейчас делаю так

```
<?php $a = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  date, COUNT(*) FROM personal043 WHERE card_id = $id GROUP BY date")  or 
die("<p>Не удается выбрать запись из базы данных</p>". mysqli_error($con));

while ($row610 = mysqli_fetch_array($a)) { ?><tr>
<td><?php echo $row610['date'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row610['COUNT(*)']; ?></td>
  </tr><?php } ; ?>
```

Он он считает каждое изменение в зубе. А надо чтоб считал каждый зуб где есть изменения не зависимо от того сколько изменений. Наприме на одном зубе могут быть 10 изменений  но он всё равно считал это как 1. Потому что изменения же на одном зубе
Screenshot [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо вытащить так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь цифра 9 это количество измененных зубов.

Comment: SELECT zubno, date, COUNT(id) as ModifiedCount FROM personal043 WHERE card_id = $id GROUP BY date, zubno

Comment: `select date, count(distinct zubno) from ...`

Comment: BINGOOOO !!! Спасибо большое Вам,   Mike , Вы очень помогли !!! ) как раз то что надо было )